# Importing data into HDFS in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hdfs

I'm trying to process some data in Google Cloud Platform (GCP), but at first, I have to put my data in HDFS. How can I import the local data into the Cloud?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should look into migration HDFS data from on premises to GCP through this [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data). The "Migrating HDFS Data from On-Premises to Google Cloud Platform" guide shows the process of moving data from HDFS to GCP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm looking for importing my data from the local (my own server) into the Cloud in order to process it in HDFS, not moving data from HDFS to GCP.